# Ideals and derived algebras.

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider L is an ideal in $g/ g '$ of codimension 1.

Let $ \pi: g \longrightarrow g / g '$ homomorph be canonical. So,

1. $ \pi^{-1} (L)$ um is ideal in g.

In fact, if $x \in \pi^{-1}(L)$ and $\in g$, then

$$\pi[x,y]=[\pi(x), \pi(y)]=0 \in L$$

because $g/g'$ is abelian and $\pi(L) \in L \subset g/g'$. So $ [x, y] \in \pi ^ {- 1} (L) $.

2. $ \pi^{-1}(L) $ have codimension 1.

i need to know if 1. is correct and how to do item 2.

Comment: For the preceding part of this question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039749/solvable-lie-algebras-derived-algebras-and-ideals).

Comment: my main question is in item 2.

Comment: I see. Item 2 has been answered above.